# inner class switch in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class that acts like a switch, where I will pass a string and it will select the inner class based on that.

```
class Router(cable_type):
  #i want the function from inside to choose which class ( switch ) based on the cable_type string provided before 
  class mega_cable:
      def cut_cable(cable_name):
          print('mega cable cut done')

  class mini_cable:
      def cut_cable(cable_name):
          print('mini cable cut done')
```

I want to say

```
my_cable_type = 'mini'
Router(my_cable_type).cut_cable('fiber_cable_1') prints  'mini cable cut done'

my_cable_type = 'mega'
Router(my_cable_type).cut_cable('fiber_cable_3') prints  'mega cable cut done'
```

How can i create this switch ?
the nested classes will have same name for methods but will do operation differently according to the type of cable provided.

Comment: Are you aware of [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)? You can return an instance of a subclass (actually, you can return an instance of any class, but then `__init__` won't be called and `isinstance` will be confusing).

Comment: You don't need an outer class for this. `Router`can simply be a function.

Comment: I am having hard time to understand this. :(

Comment: chepner , nice idea. let me try it out. I didn't think of it

Comment: If any answer here helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a function or a `dict`, not a nested class.

```
class mega_cable:
    ...


class mini_cable:
    ...
```

You can define either

```
def router(type_):
    if type_ == "mini":
         return mini_cable
    elif type_ == "mega";
         return mega_cable
    else:
         raise ValueError(f"No known class matching {type_}")

Router("mini").cut_cable(...)
```

or

```
router = {
    "mini": mini_cable,
    "mega": mega_cable
}

router["mini"].cut_cable(...)
```

If `mega_cable` and `mini_cable` are really as simple as shown here, neither of them needs to be a class either; you can just define two regular functions like `cut_mini_cable` and `cut_mega_cable`. Functions are first-class objects in Python; they don't need to be wrapped in artificial classes in order to use them as values.

Comment: easy and straight forward, thank you very much for your help. <3

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at it, written and tested:

```
class Router():
  def __init__(self, cable_type):
    self.cable_type = cable_type
  
  def cut_cable(self, cable_name):
    cable_map = {
      'mini': self.mini_cable.cut_cable,
      'mega': self.mega_cable.cut_cable
    }

    cable_map[self.cable_type](cable_name)

  class mega_cable:
      def cut_cable(cable_name):
          print('mega cable cut done')

  class mini_cable:
      def cut_cable(cable_name):
          print('mini cable cut done')

r = Router('mega')
r.cut_cable('fiber_cable_1')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help <3

Comment: quick q, with this way, ill need to replicate the functions every time I put a function in that two classes I need to map it in Router after init. ?

Comment: just to understand, you're asking if you need to do the same thing for when you add more functions to the classes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reinventing a factory, but I can't understand, why.
Maybe just use a dict instead?

```py
from typing import Type, Any, Dict

class Cable:
    def cut(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class MegaCable(Cable):
    def cut(self):
        print('mega cable cut done')


class MiniCable(Cable):
    def cut(self):
        print('mini cable cut done')

CABLE_TYPES_MAP: Dict[str, Type[Cable]] = {
    'mini': MiniCable,
    'mega': MegaCable,
}

def cable(type_: str, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> type[Cable]:
    return CABLE_TYPES_MAP[type_](*args, **kwds)

cable('mini').cut()
cable('mega').cut()
```

Or, if you really want to get some kind of a factory, I would propose to override `__class_getitem__()` (though, it have a special meaning for python typesystem), or `__new__()` and `__init_subclass__()` of a base class:

```py
In [19]: from typing import ClassVar, Optional, Type, Dict, Any
    ...:
    ...: class Cable:
    ...:     __kinds: ClassVar[Dict[str, Type['Cable']]] = {}
    ...:     _kind_: ClassVar[str]
    ...:
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def __init_subclass__(cls, *, kind: Optional[str] = None, **kwds: Any):
    ...:         cls.__kinds[cls._kind_] = cls
    ...:         return super().__init_subclass__(**kwds)
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args: Any, kind: Optional[str] = None, **kwds: Any) -> 'Cable':
    ...:         if (cls is not Cable) or (kind is None) or (kind not in cls.__kinds):
    ...:             return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwds)
    ...:         return cls.__kinds[kind](*args, **kwds)
    ...:
    ...:     def cut(self):
    ...:         print(f'Calling {self.__class__.__name__}.cut()')
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: class MiniCable(Cable):
    ...:     _kind_ = 'mini'
    ...:
    ...: class MegaCable(Cable):
    ...:     _kind_ = 'mega'
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: Cable(kind='mini').cut()
    ...: Cable(kind='mega').cut()
```

```
Calling MiniCable.cut()
Calling MegaCable.cut()
```